# CSS media query orientation and portrait device-width logic

Tags: css, media-queries, orientation, device-width

I have two divs, which I'll refer to as A & B. The desired behaviour is:

1. If the screen width is less than 400px, only A should be visible.
2. If the screen in landscape, greater than 400px in width, but less than 400px in portrait orientation, only B should be visible.
3. Else (the screen width is greater than 400px in both portrait and landscape), both A and B should be visible.

The second item is the one that's proving to be problematic.

My current approach is working for iOS devices, [which always report `min-device-width` & `max-device-width` as the portrait values](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries2.shtml) regardless of the current screen orientation, but not for android and others, where the `device-width` values change with the orientation:

```css
/* item 3 */
.a, .b {
  display: block;
}

/* item 2 */
@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-device-width: 400px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  .a { display: none; }
}

/* item 1 */
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .b { display: none }
}
```

Is it possible to implement this behaviour purely in media queries so that it works on all devices?

I'm keen to avoid JavaScript, UA Sniffing, and the use of the [deprecated media types](https://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries/#media-types) (e.g. handheld) if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to add a second media query for item 2, that targets the `max-device-height`:

```css
/* item 2a - iOS */
@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-device-width: 400px) {
  .a { display: none; }
}
/* item 2b - everything else */
@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-device-height: 400px) {
  .a { display: none; }
}
```

2a targets the iOS devices that always report `min-device-width` & `max-device-width` as the portrait values regardless of the current screen orientation.

2b targets every other device that reports `min-device-width` & `max-device-width` based on the current screen orientation. So if the screen orientation is landscape, then the `max-device-height` represents the portrait orientation screen width.

These media queries can also be combined with a `,`:

```css
/* item 2 */
@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-device-width: 400px) and (orientation: landscape), only screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-device-hieght: 400px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  .a { display: none; }
}
```